# Is there a bonus for collecting all the items in the 8-player classic Donkey Kong level?

Tags: wii-u, super-smash-bros-4

There are three items that spawn in the game as part of the classic Donkey Kong level:

- The Parasol
- The Hat
- The Purse

Collecting them plays the signature "collect" sound from the classic game and an "800" is shown in classic fashion.

Does anything special happen if a single player is able to collect all three items without dying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem like anything special happens.  I was able to collect all three (twice) and I didn't notice anything special.  The level didn't change, DK's weapons didn't change, I didn't feel any more powerful, nothing.  It looks like it's just there for effect.